# Why the width of the floated parent doesn't depends from negative margin of its child?

Tags: html, css

I have 3 blocks
  One parent, and two child. All floated.
The child blocks take the width in percent (30%, and 70%).
Second One of them (width 70%) has negative margin which is equal to its own width (`margin-left:-70%`). Therefore it shifted to the left and covers the first (width 30%) block.
But the parent block, which is also has float:left, anyway saves the width.

Please see the:
[online example](https://jsfiddle.net/f9Lj6nuc/2/)

```
.main-container {
  float:left;
}

    .sidebar-left {
      float:left;
      width: 30%;
    }

    .sidebar-right {
      width: 70%;
      margin-left:-70%;
    }
```

1. why the parent block doesn't shrinks by horizontal line?
2. how all the blocks calculate the width?

I suppose - the parent calculate its width from total width of the child blocks (And no matter that one of them is shifted). And the width of the child blocks depends from them content.
Where can I read to understand this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `.main-container` is `div` (with property `display: block`) it's width is based on parent container. Children's of `.main-container` widths are also based on parent container (`.main-container`).

So in this case, children's widths are based on parents' widths and not the other way around.

Also, consider this: if child is 35% wide as it's parent, but parent's width is decreased because of children's margins and positioning, then children's width should also decrease leading to parent's width decrease, leading to..... and so on and so forth until their all widths become 0.

Comment: Exactly!
If the parent block has float. It calculate its width from its child blocks.
So it can't to allow the shift of the child block and change the width.
Because from its width may depends the width of its children (can be with percents)).
In turn, its own width depends from its children).

Thank you!

P.S. But it works with hard coded width (via px)

Answer (score 0):

It works only when the width of the child block is exactly known!

[See the online Example](https://jsfiddle.net/62jtgsp0/7/)

```
.main-container {
  float:left;
}

    .sidebar-left {
      float:left;
      width: 300px;
    }

    .sidebar-right {
      width: 700px;
      margin-left:-700px;
    }
```

In this case the parent can change its without affecting its children elements.

To know the reason of this behavior, please look the other answer - Justas!